# How do I find out how much space a Metro App consumes in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, disk-space

For someone who is short on storage space (like on a Macbook Air -128 GB - Dual partition), each app counts towards storage. And what is the easiest way to find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8 provides an easy way to find out the size of individual apps:

```
Settings (Metro Style) -> General -> Available Storage -> View App sizes
```

[image]

You could then delete corresponding data or Apps to free storage.